# How to embed webfont using font URL in flutter application

Tags: flutter, webfonts, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

How to use font-URL to embed webfonts in flutter application ?

As per the requirement I **can't use** custom font as below :

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
```

Can anyone please let me know how to use fonts directly from URL ?

Comment: I dont think flutter supports dynamically loading fonts from url, only from assets according to their documentation

Answer (score 0):

Because of `flutter for web` still in `technical preview` maybe in the future it won't work. But for now (in my case Flutter 1.10.14 dev) we can reference font from url as in a normal web page.

Add to the `head` section of `index.html` file from `web` folder:

```html
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

and reference font from code like:

```dart
Text( 'Example', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Raleway'))
```